# Using a remote VPS for Active Directory purposes

Tags: active-directory, vps

I'm currently running Windows Server 2008 R2 at home, and I'm really enjoying having the power of Active Directory on my side.

However I currently have the server also being used as a desktop, and along with simply having users logging in and using it there are a lot of features missing from the server os that help make the desktop experience.

So I'm currently wondering if it is possible to use a cheap VPS provider to perform the AD service?

Edit: I'm also hugely interested in the potential exploits and security concerns around running a primary domain controller in the cloud.

Comment: There is no technical reason why you couldn't do this (once you have factored in security), but perhaps running a VM desktop on the server might be an option, or running the server as a VM inside a destkop operating system?

Comment: Doesn't [Kerberos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol)) handle the security side of things?

That plus encrypting the disk should cover everything. Running a VM doesn't work that well as I need gpu acceleration on the desktop and having the desktop dependant on a VM it runs is asking for trouble.

Comment: Desktop dependencies on AD aren't clear cut, particularly with cached credentials, but in any case, you could run the vm as a service so it is running prior to login.  So the answer to your question is "yes", but was there something more you were trying to get out of this question?

Comment: Basically, I wasn't 100% sure about the security sides of things and I wanted a more clear view before I went ahead (other than "surely Kerberos is secure enough")

Comment: A VPS that can support the ADDS would be quite expensive though. You'll need at least 1GB of RAM to avoid exessive paging (and loads of event log warnings of the server being unresponsive.) My suggestion is use an old laptop as the domain controller.

Comment: @billc.cn $129.50USD/yr isn't too expensive, particularly when you factor in running costs and data redundancy.

Note that it's solely for home personal use (~10 users at the maximum), and mainly just for authentication requests.

I do have a spare laptop that is currently being used as a minecraft server so I could look into joining the two. Thanks for you input.

Comment: Could you please tell me which hosting provider that is? All the ones that I've looked at would cost twice that amount for 1GB memory.

Comment: http://burst.net/